# COUNT by month (Unix Timestamp) in one table1 and write the result into table 2

Tags: mysql, count, timestamp

I have table1 on which I do this query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.TSTAMP), "%Y-%m") AS "timePeriod", COUNT(*) AS "prod1"
```

gives a perfect me 2 column result with col'timePeriod' and col'prod1'. I would now like to update table2.prod1 where primary key is 'timePeriod'.

I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you specified

```
INSERT 
IGNORE // include this if you want conflicts to be ignored
INTO table2 (
    timePeriod,
    prod1
)
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.TSTAMP), "%Y-%m"),
    COUNT(*)

// you didn't include a "FROM" so added relevant place here
FROM table1 

// Include this if you want conflicts to append to the existing row
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod1 = prod1 + VALUES(prod1) 

// Include this if you want conflicts to replace the existing row
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod1 = VALUES(prod1)
```

Comment: Why has this been voted down?  I know the above would function in the way requested so if I've been doing something fundamentally flawed I would appreciate critique

Comment: When I use

`INSERT 
INTO table2 (
    timePeriod,
    prod1
)
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(TSTAMP), "%Y-%m") AS "timePeriod",
    COUNT(*) AS 'prod1'
 FROM table1
 WHERE ACTION='prod1'
GROUP BY timePeriod;
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod1 = VALUES(prod1) `

the data is inserted correctly, but I still get the message "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pprod1 = VALUES(prod1) Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: Hooray!! My fault, the semicolon after GROUP BY timePeriod was the problem. Thanks a lot, this place rocks

Comment: Good to hear - if a solution here has answered your problem please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this... I could not test it out though.

```
UPDATE table2 AS T2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(TSTAMP), "%Y-%m") AS "timePeriod",
    COUNT(*) AS prod1 FROM table1
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(TSTAMP), "%Y-%m")
) AS T1 USING (timePeriod)
SET T2.prod1 = T1.prod1;
```

Comment: With this I get `codeError : Unknown column 't.TSTAMP' in 'field list'`

Comment: My question was not phrased correctly, this solution works perfectly as an update!